# Mobile device ignores my css rule, why?

Tags: css, html

I have the following css rule for my mobile menu, but the problem is that it ignores the postion statement on my mobile device, but not on my desktop browser, ( Chrome, Firefox IE etc )

The CSS rule:

```
background:#000 url("images/nav-icon.png") no-repeat;background-position:
right 15px top 10px; (DISPLAYED AT THE TOP LEFT *)
```

Have alos tried these combinations.

```
background-image:url("images/nav-icon.png");background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right 15px top 10px; (DISPLAYED AT THE TOP LEFT *)

background:#000 url("images/nav-icon.png") right 15px top 10px no-repeat;
(NOT DISPLAYED AT ALL *)
```

*
On the mobile device.

One of them isn't displayed at all, but two of them in the top left corner. See which one above.

And now to my question, is there a problem with my combination or does mobile devices not support these combinations?

Thanks in adavance Jack

Answer (score 0):

Some mobile devices cannot do that. i.e. iPhones or Webkit browsers.

Try to find another way (there are many css hacks if you google them) or use javascript!

Make sure you test your website on multiple devices. I go to Future Shop or Bestbuy and will test my responsive website/web app out there on tablets, large screen computers and a series of mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to specify the background position with the four-value syntax? That's still an [open proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position). If you know the width of the element you are applying it to, you can set it from the right using a percentage value.

> Maybe the best solution would be to make a span element inside the div element, and position the span element instead of the background-image

If you're going to apply the background to a span, you'll need to give it a `display: block;` or similar, so you might as well use a div in that case and absolutely position it with a z-index below that of the elements you want it behind (you'll need to give them a `position: relative;` to make `z-index` work.